# _ViewStart.cshtml with nested layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a following project structure:

[image: Project structure]

_ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

_Red.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Red";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

_Blue.cshtml does **not** have a Layout specified explicitly.

Now if a try to render Index.cshtml using _Red.cshtml layout, _Layout.cshtml is also applied hierarchically. So basically we have a nested templates chain _Layout->Red->Our page

But if I try to render Index.cshtml using _Blue.cshtml, _Layout.cshtml is **not** applied.
I was expecting that _Layout.cshtml would be applied to _Blue.cshtml by convention using _viewstart. Instead I get Index.cshtml page with only _Blue.cshtml template being applied.

Am I wrong in my assumptions?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View("Index");
}
```

So, I am returning ViewResult, not PartialViewResult ;)

Comment: Are you returning View or PartialView from controller?

Comment: @Chuck Norris: sorry, forgot to mention it, I am returning View("Index")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong in your assumption. If a layout is specified (_Blue.cshtml), the layout in _Viewstart will NOT be applied. _Viewstart is for your default layout so you don't have to specify it on every page.

Comment: Well, I was expecting it to be applied to _Blue.cshtml, where layout is not specified. And after that by applying _Blue.cshtml to my page I was expecting to get both. It doesn't work in that way?

Comment: No, the layout page in _viewstart is only applied to normal pages, not to other layout pages. If I can find the docs that describe the exact behaviour I'll post the link.